# How to write a function which calculate the midpoint between 2 points in python?

Tags: python

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
"""
PRE: p1 and p2 are Point objects (from the graphics module)
POST: a new Point equidistant from and co-linear with p1 and p2
is computed and returned
```

Write a function midpoint with the following specification

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What graphics module are you using? (pypi contains several dozen, none named 'graphics') What does the interface of a Point look like?

If Point has named attributes (like p.x, p.y, etc) you could do something like

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return Point((p1.x+p2.x)/2, (p1.y+p2.y)/2)
```

If Point can be accessed as a list (like p[0], p[1], etc) you could instead do

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return Point((p1[0]+p2[0])/2, (p1[1]+p2[1])/2)
```

If Point has Point addition and scalar division or multiplication overloaded, you could do

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return (p1+p2)/2     # or *0.5
```

(although strictly speaking adding two Points should be meaningless, and subtracting one point from another should give you a Vector - thus

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return p1 + (p2-p1)/2     # or *0.5
```

Answer (score 6):

You'd write it the same way you write any other function:

```
def midpoint(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return ((x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2)
```

or something like that. It depends on whether you represent points as individual coordinates or objects or lists etc.

Comment: def midpoint(p1, p2):                                              PRE: p1 and p2 are Point objects (from the graphics module)
POST: a new Point equidistant from and co-linear with p1 and p2
is computed and returned    This is the content. The question is Write a function midpoint with this specificiation

Comment: How to represent in the way that the question asks?

Comment: @hkus10: You can calculate and assert distances (Pythagoras theorem, you know). You can check collinearity by inferring the equation of the right line that passes through the two points and assert that midpoint is a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Calculate them yourself?

The midway point between two points is their average. That is,

```
P_mid = (P1 + P2) / 2
```

It's up to you how a "point" is represented. It could be 2D, 3D, or even nD. You might want to implement `__add__` and `__div__` and other "numerical" operations.

Comment: Since P1 is a point object which is P1 = (X1, Y1), (P1 + P2)/2 is not able to give the x and y answers for the midpoint. So, How to use P1 and P2 which are point objects to present the midpoint.

Comment: Of course it can, _if_ you have defined division and addition for this class of objects. It is perfectly possible in Python, but is probably an overkill for you now.

Comment: Can you provide some hints how to do it?

Comment: If class `Point` is defined in a separate `graphics` module, it may not be possible to change its implementation so it has the necessary numerical operations.

Comment: This is probably getting beyond the scope of the OP's question, but even if `Point` is defined in a separate module, changing its implementation is *still* possible, in a monkey-patching fashion, without too much fuzz in Python.

Answer (score 4):

How about using Numpy?

If the points are represented by numpy.array, their dimension doesn't matter.

For example, consider 2D.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-1, -1])
y = np.array([1, 1])

mid1 = (x + y)/2
# or
mid2 = np.mean([x, y])
```

> NumPy is the fundamental package needed for scientific computing with Python.

visit [Link](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the question is about "Point" objects in the module named `graphics`.

As per the documentation I am providing in the reference, the Point class has `getX()` and `getY() accessors to fetch the X and Y coordinates of the point respectively.

So the solution could be like this

```
            def midpoint(p1, p2):

                        mx =  (p1.getX() + p2.getX())/2.0
                        my =  (p1.getY() + p2.getY())/2.0
                        return Point(mx,my)
```

or

```
           def midpoint(p1,p2):

                       l = Line(p1,p2)
                       return l.getCenter()
```

Reference-
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division

def midpoint(p1, p2):
    if len(p1) != len(p2):
        raise TypeError('Points are from differing dimensions')
    return map(lambda (e1, e2): (e1 + e2) / 2, zip(p1, p2))
```

### Update0

Since it seems nobody actually answered the question in the form you wanted (except me `;)`), here's the simplified version for 2 dimensional points:

```
def midpoint(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0] + p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2
```

Comment: I am a beginner@@ I have never seen some of those functions! My approach is                                                       def midpoint(p1, p2):
    p1 = (x1, y1)
    p2 = (x2, y2)
    return midpoint((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)                                                                               Can you help me to fix it@@

Comment: +1 for `from __future__ import division`.  Otherwise you're in for a nasty surprise with points that happen to have integer coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the answers so far have involved averaging. Here are two somewhat novel approaches (based on [Prof Daniel Lemire's article](https://lemire.me/blog/2022/12/06/fast-midpoint-between-two-integers-without-overflow/)) using bitwise operations that take advantage of the fact the point will be integers. If you're using floating point math, these won't work.

```
def midpoint (x, y):
    return ((x^y)>>1) + (x&y)
```

```
def midpoint2 (x, y):
    return (x|y) - ((x^y)>>1)
```